# How can veriable artificial gravity be created in a full colony on another planet, or moon?

Tags: colonization, artificial-gravity

Gravity on other planets or moons do not equal that of the Earth. If an Earth-equivalent gravity is required then can this level of gravity, or any level of gravity, be created artificially?

Artificial gravity could be generated in a vehicle by moving the vehicle in a circle. If a banked, circular path were provided, occupants within the vehicle could feel as if they were under an increase in the force of gravity. If several parallel circular paths were provided — such as maglev tracks — trains could be placed on the tracks that could act as living quarters for people or materials that might require a gravity similar to Earth. If the diameter of the tracks are approximately one mile, then the occupants would probably not feel the Coriolis effect caused by moving in a circle. People and supplies could be interchanged between vehicles moving along the parallel tracks with the same radial velocity.

If there were requirements for communities to be constructed, such that the occupants (families with small children) would feel conditions similar to Earth, or Mars, could these variable-gravity facilities be constructed?